# What is the temperature at which sodium hydroxide decomposes at? And how would you collect the condensation?

Tags: decomposition

I don't think this is an extremely tough question, but I can't really find that much information online on this reaction. I found a video about the decomposition of calcium hydroxide, though I'm not sure how much the decomposition temperature differs between these two metal hydroxides. I also saw that the person was using a blow torch (I'm assuming) to decompose the calcium hydroxide, but I was told that test tubes weren't to be used under strong flames.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm also looking for a way to collect the water vapour that comes from the reaction, or prove that there was H2O formed from the reaction, e.g. using cobalt chloride indicators.

Comment: We see from the currently posted answer this won't work with sodium hydroxide, but why were you looking at that hydroxide? Telling that may neutralize the downvote and close vote I am seeing, and perhaps allow us to identify alternatives that will work for you.

Comment: [NaOH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_hydroxide) has reportedly the boiling point 1388 deg C, so the condensate would be NaOH again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably never, unless perhaps you throw the stuff onto an incandescent light bulb filament (are there still those?) or the surface of the Sun.

In thermodynamic terms, hydroxides decompose on heating because the steam that's generated is a favorable entropy effect when the hydroxide is still condensed and thus more "ordered". But alkali metal hydroxides present a problem. Since the ions are all singly charged and a strong enthalpy effect from the exothermic reaction between the (strongly basic) oxide and water must be overcome, the alkali metal hydroxides may actually boil before they decompose. Then you lose the entropy advantage.

Let's look at the numbers, as rendered by Wikipedia as of November 2023. [Lithium hydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_hydroxide) melts at 462°C and then decomposes at 924°C while still liquid, so with that alkali all is well for decomposition thermodynamics (albeit at a higher temperature than most other hydroxides). [Sodium hydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_hydroxide), which is a stronger base itself and forms from a more strongly basic oxide, melts at 323°C and boils at 1388°C — with **no reported decomposition before boiling,** at least from Wikipedia. Not surprisingly, the same result carries over to the heavier alkali hydroxides.

And so, it appears that you can't realistically expect sodium hydroxide (or heavier alkali hydroxides) to decompose thermally at all, at least not by the mechanism that works for lithium hydroxide and for hydroxides outside the alkali group.